# Querying nested JSON within list

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a table called schoolList that looks like this:

| school | registered |
| --- | --- |
| School 1 | [{"id":1,"displayId":11,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"John","notes":null},{"id":2,"displayId":12,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Kate","notes":null},{"id":3,"displayId":13,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Stacy","notes":null},{"id":4,"displayId":14,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Matt","notes":null},{"id":5,"displayId":15,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Lucy","notes":null},{"id":6,"displayId":16,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Dan","notes":null},{"id":7,"displayId":17,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Ethan","notes":null}] |
| School 2 | [{"id":1,"displayId":11,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Brandon","notes":null},{"id":2,"displayId":12,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Bayden","notes":null},{"id":3,"displayId":13,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Nick","notes":null},{"id":4,"displayId":14,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Leslie","notes":null},{"id":5,"displayId":15,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Amy","notes":null},{"id":6,"displayId":16,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"George","notes":null},{"id":7,"displayId":17,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Michelle","notes":null}] |

I want to extract the name values from the registered column where displayId=16. So I should have returned "Dan", "George".

I have tried:

```
select registered.name from schoolList lateral view explode(registered) where registered.displayId='16'
```

But this gives me this error:

```
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '.'.(line 1, pos 83)

== SQL ==
select registered.name from schoollist lateral view explode(registered) where registered.displayId='16'
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup might vary depending on how the data is coming in, but assuming it's just a plain string. If you are hitting the data initially when it has an appropriate data type you can probably ignore the from_json + schema and just go straight to explode.

There might be something clever where Databricks can infer the schema. Something to explore.

"schema_of_json(raw_json_as_string)" is good to get the schema copy/pastable from the editor, but the return type isn't compatible as an argument for from_json. Probably solvable.

```sql
    create or replace temporary view some_test_data as (
    select
    '[{"id":1,"displayId":11,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"John","notes":null},{"id":2,"displayId":12,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Kate","notes":null},{"id":3,"displayId":13,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Stacy","notes":null},{"id":4,"displayId":14,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Matt","notes":null},{"id":5,"displayId":15,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Lucy","notes":null},{"id":6,"displayId":16,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Dan","notes":null},{"id":7,"displayId":17,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"East High School","name":"Ethan","notes":null}]
    ' as raw_json_as_string
    union 
    select
    '[{"id":1,"displayId":11,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Brandon","notes":null},{"id":2,"displayId":12,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Bayden","notes":null},{"id":3,"displayId":13,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Nick","notes":null},{"id":4,"displayId":14,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Leslie","notes":null},{"id":5,"displayId":15,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Amy","notes":null},{"id":6,"displayId":16,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"George","notes":null},{"id":7,"displayId":17,"category":"Schooling","schoolName":"North Middle School","name":"Michelle","notes":null}]'
    );
    
    select extracted_elements['name']
      from (
          select explode(from_json(raw_json_as_string,
                        "ARRAY<STRUCT<id: BIGINT, displayId: BIGINT, category: STRING, schoolName: STRING, name: STRING>>")) as extracted_elements
            from some_test_data
          )
     where extracted_elements['displayID'] = 16;
```